# react child (found: object with keys{...} If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How are you? I have a couple of doubts! How can I access the inheritance of an object?
I am trying to get the data from NewConfirmed, which has "Global"

img Console.log:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJGcH.png

For now I can only take the data "Date"

```js
stats = () => {
    const { dataCovid } = this.props;
    if (this.props.loader) {
      return (/**/ );
    }
    return (
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-md-4'>
          <div className='card stat-card'>
            <div className='card-body'>
              <h5 className='card-title'>Total de Nuevos    Contagio:</h5>
              <h2 className='float-right'> {dataCovid.Date}</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Now if I try to call datacovid.Global, in console I get the following:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {NewConfirmed, TotalConfirmed, NewDeaths, TotalDeaths, NewRecovered, TotalRecovered})
```

if you assigned the value of NewConfimed it throws me

```
 TypeError: dataCovid.Global is undefined
```

Comment: Hi David, it doesn't look like you've posted the full code for your React component. We'll be able to help more if we can see all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you are getting data via Ajax call, then probably during initial rendering, `dataCovid.Global` is undefined.

Try with `{dataCovid.Global && dataCovid.Global.NewConfirmed}` to avoid the error.

- You can not render just whole Object inside `render()`, rather try printing the required object properties using in loop/map.